# Cookies vs Sessions | I get different result

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-cookies

What I want to achieve,

1. The user enters the `one_page.php` and we `require('form.php')` for user to fill while `$_SESSION['foo']` isn't set.
2. The user submits the form and a `$_SESSION['foo']` is set.
3. We `header ('Location: one_page.php')` (practically like reloading)
4. We get in the `if` we `unset($_SESSION['foo'])` and we `require('something_else.php')`.
5. If the user reload the `site.php` or re-enter it he's going to get the `form.php` again.

I will not show you the actual code because it's too big and I don't want to paste only parts of it but I reproduced the problem at two examples bellow.

---

Using `cookies` the code were running exactly as intended.

Using `session` it's like we get in this `if` we `unset($_SESSION['foo'])` but then we leave the `if` and get into `else`.

*When I set the session for example at `page1.php` and redirect the user to `page2.php` to unset the session everything seems fine. I just can't get it work when I create the session at the same page where I unset it.*

---

### **Examples**

**Using Cookies** *We get in the IF when we press the button*

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        setcookie('foo', 'foo', time() +3600);
        header('Location: one_page.php');
    }

    if (isset($_COOKIE['foo'])) {
        setcookie('foo', 'foo', time() -3600);
        echo "We entered the IF";   //require('something_else.php')
    } else {
        echo "We entered the ELSE"; //require('form.php')
    }
?>
<!-- The form which is required in my case -->
<html>
    <body>
        <form method="post">
            <button name="submit">Button</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html
```

**Using Sessions** *We are in the ELSE no matter what*

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $_SESSION['foo'] = "foo";   
        header('Location: one_page.php');
    }

    if (isset($_SESSION['foo'])) {
        unset($_SESSION['foo']);
        echo "We entered the IF";    //require('something_else.php')
    } else {
        echo "We entered the ELSE";  //require('form.php')
    }
?>
<!-- The form which is required in my case -->
<html>
    <body>
        <form method="post">
            <button name="submit">Button</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I could just use cookies but this is bugging me so much for hours now.

Any thoughts?

Comment: add `exit;` after the header call. it may be making it to the unset before the redirect kicks in

Comment: Thank you Dagon, thank you so much it worked... something so simple tortured me for so many hours. I'm still novice tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `exit()` just after the `header('Location: one_page.php')` fixed the problem.

The `unset($_SESSION['foo'])` were running before the redirection as Dagon said.

**Fixed**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $_SESSION['foo'] = "foo";   
        header('Location: one_page.php');
        exit();
    }

    if (isset($_SESSION['foo'])) {
        unset($_SESSION['foo']);
        echo "We entered the IF";    //require('something_else.php')
    } else {
        echo "We entered the ELSE";  //require('form.php')
    }
?>
<!-- The form which is required in my case -->
<html>
    <body>
        <form method="post">
            <button name="submit">Button</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thank you Dagon!